# stopping sounds without stopping bgm as3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

flash pro. as 3.0.
animation . 
almost no codes except ends of scenes having :

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
if(SoundMixer.areSoundsInaccessible() == false)
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
}
else
{
  trace("There are inaccessible sounds.");
}
```

and at the end of animation, a code for replay button.

so... 
i got this scene, with this specific bgm ,
 individual frame layer. 
and the sounds at another layer. 
 what i want is to stop the sound without stopping the bgm . 
 (yes, i know the above code wouldn't work as it stops all sounds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion better way for controlling sounds in timeline is:

1) in flash project library make right click on your sound and select "Properties..." context menu item ->

"Sound Properties" window opened ->

goto "ActionScript" tab ->

switch on "Export for ActionScript" ->

enter some class name into "Class" text input (for example "MySound1") ->

click "Ok"

Now you sound avaiable from ActionScript

2) remove sound from timeline

3) when you need start play this sound use code

```
var mySound:Sound = new MySound1();
var mySoundChannel:SoundChannel = mySound.play(0);
```

where MySound1 is class name which you set in Sound Properties window.

when you need stop your sound use code

`mySoundChannel.stop();`

Using this way you will able to start/stop any your sounds without mutting other sounds.

Comment: i was told to try to keep everything in one flash file... T^T

Comment: What prevent you to do so? Embed sounds into flash library (they located there already) and use. I not write that you need load sounds at runtime.