# Need help attaching a sound clip to a movie clip item

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

i'm having difficulty attaching a sound clip to on object so that when it's clicked, a sound will play out. I don't have a seperate actionscript file to my game, the actionscript is within the timeline. My soundtrack is in my library and my movie clip has the appropriate instance name, here is the code;

```
import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundTransform;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel
    import flash.net.URLRequest;


GBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,muteBtnPressed);


var s:Sound = new Sound;
s.load(new URLRequest("song.wav"));
var sc:SoundChannel = s.play(0,1000);
sc.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);



var soundMuted:Boolean = false;




function muteBtnPressed(evt:MouseEvent){
    if(soundMuted==true){
        soundMuted = false;
        sc.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
        GBtn.gotoAndStop("on");
    } else {
        (soundMuted == false){
            soundMuted = true;

        sc.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
        GBtn.gotoAndStop("off");
    } 
}
```

at the moment, this is code for a mute button, but I will reverse this eventualy to play when clicked. Any advice would be greatly appreciated as my work is in for tomorrow and I'm getting a bit behind! Thank you!!

Comment: If you want play sound from library check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630051/stopping-sounds-without-stopping-bgm-as3/8631996#8631996

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sound is in the library set it to export for Actionscript with the class name "Song". Then replace these two lines

```
var s:Sound = new Sound;
s.load(new URLRequest("song.wav"));
```

With this

```
var s:Sound = new Song();
```

This will instantiate your library sound.